# What was the first elementary proof that $\pi(x)=o(x)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, ho.history-overview, elementary-proofs

Denote by $\pi(x)$ the number of primes $\leq x$. I'm interested in knowing who came up with the **first elementary proof** that $\pi(x)=o(x)$.

I know that Chebyshev demonstrated  elementarily before Hadamard and de la Vallee-Poussin the slightly stronger result that $\pi(x)=O(x/\log x)$.

Comment: According to Hardy and Wright (sixth edition, p.498), the divergence of the product $\prod(1-p^{-1})$ was proved by Euler. They show in $\S 22.7$ that this implies that $\pi(x)=o(x)$.

Comment: (..and please stop editing your question).

Comment: There is also a proof in Landau's Handuch, $\S15$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leonhard Euler knew that the infinite product:

$$ \prod_{p \textrm{ prime}} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p} \right)^{-1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} $$

is divergent (and used this to prove the infinitude of primes), so would have also known that the product:

$$ \prod_{p \textrm{ prime}} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p} \right) $$

tends to zero. In other words:

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \prod_{p < n\textrm{ prime}} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p} \right) = 0 $$

Observe that the product in the last expression is the density of integers which are coprime to the set $\{ p < n \textrm{ such that } p \textrm{ is prime} \}$; this trivially implies that primes have zero upper density.

Comment: So, Euler would have known the answer if he asked the question, but *did* he actually make this connection?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Apparentely it was Legendre. See his "Essai sur la théorie des nombres" (1808 edition) p.394. He cites Euler.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Excellent point. He couldn't have asked this question as stated, because little-O notation didn't exist at the time of Euler. The main issue rests on whether the idea of (upper) density existed.